# Database Schema To Another Database Schema Converter

Tags: sql, database, migration

Is there anyway that I could generate database from one schema to another?

For example, I would like to run my application from oracle to sql server or from sql server to postgresql?

I'm looking for something that's free....

Also I would like to know if there's a schema initializer to go with it

thanks a lot

Comment: I was writing dbTamer with the aim of doing this, but it has been lying unused on Sourceforge for a while. The source code is all there if you want to look.

Comment: If you limit yourself to the SQL command set supported by both servers, there is no reason your tables and queries won't work both places...  Of course, that may be restrictive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I found so far is to use Squirrel's DBCOPY plugin. It really does the job

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really fall under the "free" category, but if you already have the tools (Microsoft Visual Studio and appropriate .NET providers), it might be a possibility.

The idea is to generate a data model from one database in Visual Studio and then use the Model First functionality to go from the conceptual model to another database.  The steps would be something like this:

- In a VS2010 application, add a new item to the project:  `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`
- Choose your existing database the source for this new model and select the desired tables and click through the wizard.
- After the model is created, make sure the conceptual model is visible (.edmx file).  In the properties for the model, there should be a `DDL Generation Template` option. Change this to the desired target type.  This is the really iffy part; I don't know how many providers support this, but a quick search seemed to turn up at least one for Postgres.
- Right click on the model and choose `Generate Database from Model`.  This should produce the DDL for the new database.

This certainly would not lend itself well to an automated process, but for a one-time process, it might be okay.